# What is the Probability of EXACTLY ONE of these three events occurring?

Tags: probability

Events:
 P (A) = 0.43, P(B)= 0.37, P (C) = 0.28

Extra information:
 P (A ∩ B) = 0.19, P (B ∩ C) = 0.12, P (A ∪ B) = 0.61, P (A ∪ C) = 0.71

Multiple Choice Options: 
(a) 0.20 (b) 0.32 (c) 0.46 (d) 0.54 (e) none of these

Part of the question was solving for P(B), which I easily found. 
I am having some difficulty solving this question, however. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps make a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(A\cup C)=P(A)+P(C)-P(A\cap C)$$

$$ 0.71=.43+.28-P(A\cap C)$$

$$\Rightarrow P(A \cap C)= 0 $$

$$P(\textrm{Exactly one of \{A,B,C}\})=$$

$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2 P(A\cap B) - 2P(B\cap C)$$

$$= .43+.37+.28 - 2(.19) -2(.12) $$ 
$$ =  0.46$$

The answer is (c).